# Error al querer parsear JSON

Tags: json, xcode, swift3, alamofire

Hola Tengo una consulta al ejecutar mi aplicación me da el siguiente error y no estoy descubriendo a que se debe agradecería mucho sus ayudas!. Desde ya muchas gracias!
adjunto parte de mi código

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire



extension MockData {

    static func index(completion: @escaping ([MockData]) -> Void) {

             Alamofire.request("https://www.dropbox.com/s/fem028u5ok95270/Clases.json?dl=1") .responseJSON { (response) in
            print(response)
            var users = [MockData]()
            if let objects = response.result.value {
                let json = objects as! NSDictionary
                let list = json["Horarios"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]

            for object in list! {
                users.append(MockData(dictionary: object))
            }
            }
            completion(users)

        }

    }
}
```

Mi Clase MockData.Swift

```
import UIKit

class MockData: NSObject {

var id : String?
var dia : DiasClases?
var materia : String?
var horario : String?
var seccion : String?
var profesor : String?
//var aula : String?
//var obs : String?
var HorarioArray = [MockData]()


init(dictionary: [String: AnyObject]){

    self.id = dictionary["id"] as? String
    self.dia = dictionary["dia"] as? DiasClases
    self.materia = dictionary["materia"] as? String
    self.seccion = dictionary["seccion"] as? String
    self.profesor = dictionary["profesor"] as? String
    //self.aula = dictionary["aula"] as? String
    //self.obs = dictionary["obs"] as? String

}


}

enum DiasClases {
case Lunes
case Martes
case Miercoles
case Jueves
case Viernes
case Sabado

static func AllValues() -> [DiasClases] {
    return [Lunes, Martes, Miercoles, Jueves, Viernes, Sabado]
}
}
```

[image: Imagen de error]

Comment: podrias colocar el error, ya que en la imagen no se distingue bien.

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: La línea let list = json["Horarios"] as? [[String: AnyObject]]
te da un error porque "Horarios" no existe, es "Horario"

Comment: Me funciono de maravilla, te agradezco! , lo que no me funciona es la parte en que cargue por ejemplos las materias en su día correspondientes no se donde me estoy equivocando te puedo pasar mas fracciones de mi código también